# Is command line the only way to configure wildfly 10 programatically?

Tags: java, command-line, jboss, wildfly, jmx

From what I can tell, the docs all point to the command line interface.  We have a java interface that can call a section of our API that is generic that uses JMX for weblogic to configure everything.  Our code would be more simple if I kept it similar between the two server types.

What I am finding is that everything I would normally configure in JMX (JDBC, Mail Sessions, JMS, etc) is documented to be called by wildfly on command line.

Is this the normal (recommended) way to configure wildfly so it is ready for your EAR deployment?

Comment: You should be able to use JMX. Maybe have a look at http://planet.jboss.org/post/remote_jmx_access_to_wildfly_or_jboss_as7_using_jconsole. There other ways as well, but JMX should work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the [native management API](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/The+native+management+API) - **ModelControllerClient** - in Java to do your configuration tasks:

```
ModelControllerClient client = ModelControllerClient.Factory
        .create(new ModelControllerClientConfiguration.Builder().setHostName(HOSTNAME).setPort(9990)
                .setConnectionTimeout(36000).build());

ModelNode operation = new ModelNode();
operation.get("operation").set("whoami");
operation.get("verbose").set("true");

ModelNode result = client.execute(operation);

System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Other way is to use the [HTTP management API](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/The+HTTP+management+API) and do the same by this way using any fitting client (e.g. curl):

```
curl --digest -u admin:passwd.123 -L -D - http://localhost:9990/management \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"operation":"whoami","verbose":"true","json.pretty":1}'
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed the entire admin guide that mentions this.  I went over it and have it working locally.  Seems alot easier than JMX / Mbeans.